# How to print the text inside input tag

Tags: javascript

Here is some code of my HTML web page.

```
<input id="sin" type="radio" name="oper">C
<input id="cos" type="radio" name="oper">B
<input id="tg" type="radio" name="oper">A
```

I have all input tags in variable:

```
var inputs, index;
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    document.write(inputs[index]);
}
```

How can I get the text(C,B,A) from all the inputs and print them on browser.
I tried with textNode,value,innerHTML,innerTEXT etc. Nothing worked at all. I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Using `document.querySelector("#sin").value` will return the text entered into an `input` element. Also, tags that cannot have content (void elements) such as an `input` tag should not have inner content. If you specify a `value` attribute for your radio buttons then you can access them using `element.value` like shown above.

Comment: If you want to get inner content, you have to embed `input` inside of `label` tag, See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086318/using-innerhtml-with-input

Answer (score 1):

You're doing is wrong. Texts are outside `input` elements so you won't be able to get it. Rather put those text in `value` attribute in `input` element, like below and then try to read it with `.value`

```
<input id="sin" type="radio" name="oper" value="C">C
<input id="cos" type="radio" name="oper"  value="B">B
<input id="tg" type="radio" name="oper" value="A">A
```

Comment: `value` is not a function and doesn't need parentheses. You can just access the elements value using `element.value`.

Comment: Thanks. excuse the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a value to each of the `input` elements and go from there like @Tanner Dolby said:

```js
// javascript
document.getElementById('write-button').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( (input) => document.write(input.value) );
}
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<input id="sin" type="radio" name="oper" value="C">C
<input id="cos" type="radio" name="oper" value="B">B
<input id="tg" type="radio" name="oper" value="A">A
<div>
    <button type="button" id="write-button">write values</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the inputs with a label tag and then access its value from the input tag with parentElement.textContent.

```js
var inputs, index;
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    document.write(inputs[index].parentElement.textContent);
}
console.log("JavaScript is amazing!");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
<head>
  
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My New Project!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <!--  Styles  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>
  
<body>
  <label for="sin">
    <input id="sin" type="radio" name="oper">C
  </label>
  <label for="cos">
    <input id="cos" type="radio" name="oper">B
  </label>
  <label for="tg">
    <input id="tg" type="radio" name="oper">A
  </label>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```